# Finding one value in relation to the value of another column

Tags: sql, select, top-n

I've got a table that looks a bit like this

[image]

What I want to do is find the pressure value of the earliest Start_Time

So in this case I want the value "5"

How can I do this? I'm not sure of how to relate 2 values this way

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik anything in this case, I don't mind, I just want to get an idea of a way that this could be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the first value by start_time so sort by start_time and take the first one:

```
Select top 1 Pressure, Start_Time  
From yourTable 
Order by Start_Time asc
```

Comment: Thanks! what would you use to find the value for the last Start_Time on the database?

Comment: invert the order by with desc

Comment: If an answer is going to be upvoted, I would recommend Mureinik's because that answer specifies the Standard SQL solution.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the idea is to sort by one column, query the other and limit the result set. In ANSI SQL you could do this with a `fetch` caluse:

```sql
SELECT pressure
FROM person
ORDER BY start_time
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Note that specific RDBMSs may have slightly different syntax. MS SQL-Server uses the `top` syntax as [Carra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68225504/2422776) suggests, while MySQL uses the `limit` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

short answer :

```
 select Pressure from theTable 
    order by Start_Time asc limit 1
```